# Django: How to conditionally define fields in a model mixin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my back-end (API) site, there are certain fields that are common to **most** models, but not all.  I have been using mixins for those fields so that I can include them for the models they apply to, and omit them from the ones they don't.  For example:

```py
class AddressPhoneModelMixin(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Address'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_('Country'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('Phone'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('Mobile Phone'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('Fax'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

But I have other such mixins, and when a model needs to include all fields, the model definition gets to be quite long:

```py
class Client(AddressPhoneModelMixin, DateFieldsModelMixin, models.Model):
```

And I now have other "common" fields I want to add, so it's only going to get worse.  I want to keep all these common fields in one place for DRY, but also in case anything changes about a field, I only have one place to make the changes.

My idea is to have one mixin called CommonFieldsModelMixin, so that I will have only one mixin to include in the model definition.  But for those models that don't need certain fields, the field definitions would all be wrapped in conditionals.  Taking the above mixin as an example, and adding a conditional "Email Address" field, this is what I want to do:

```py
class CommonFieldsModelMixin(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Address'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name=_('Country'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    if include_email:    # <--this is what I want to add
        email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name=_('Email Address'),
            blank=True,
        )
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('Phone'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('Mobile Phone'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name=_('Fax'),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then when using the mixin on a model, it would be something like this:

```py
class Client(CommonFieldsModelMixin, models.Model):
    include_email = True

    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Client'),
        max_length=100,
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('Status'),
        max_length=25,
    )
```

Notice the `include_email = True` property.  In reality, all fields would be wrapped in conditionals, but this is intended as a simple example.

My question is, how can I access the `include_email` property of the parent from within the mixin?  There isn't a `self` to use.  I've also tried using `super()`, but that didn't work either.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

And I'll also need to do the same (or similar) thing for the serializers.  So if that would work differently, any suggestions there would be appreciated.

Comment: why not keep the model fields and put conditional logics in serializers or whatever you are using for API?

Comment: I would suggest you to consider composition instead of inheritance for some of these fields / mixins. For example, you might want to add an address FK to many models instead of having address fields within these models. Having several mixins in your class isn't a problem though. You're going to run into lots of issues with what you're trying to achieve with `CommonFieldsModelMixin `... I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @ruddra, we don't want the fields in the table(s).

Comment: @François,  What is "composition"? Also, I don't understand "you might want to add an address FK to many models instead of having address fields within these models."  Sounds like those two things are the same... "add address to many models" ... "instead of having address fields within these models".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @François, ignore my question about "composition".  I just Googled it.  Sorry, should have done that before posting.
Oh, and I just understood the second part of your message, re: address FK vs. address fields.